# I recently got a Lenovo Ideapad (S10-3t) and I don't know where to get Wi-Fi drivers

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, netbook, broadcom

It came with Windows 7 Starter on it and I just upgraded to Ultimate. Both 32bit. I know it's a Broadcom card, but I'm not sure how to find the model number (I'll post it if someone can tell me how). I have been searching for the drivers for hours and nothing has worked.

First place I went was to Lenovo's support site and they didn't work. There was also two links that gave the same file by accident (maybe that's the one I need). I then tried about 20 more and still no luck. I am dual booting it with Ubuntu and it automatically prompted me to download the un-approved driver. Then it worked.

Has anyone else had this problem with Windows 7? This netbook is essentially useless to me if the Wi-Fi doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all drivers for S10-3t [here](http://consumersupport.lenovo.com/ot/en/driversdownloads/drivers_list.aspx?categoryid=45252) (look under Network: Wireless LAN).

Comment: I've tried them with no luck. Also, the first and third link are the same ones. One is supposed to be 65MB, but it's just 15MB again. Maybe that's the driver I need :)

Comment: Well, that's where I downloaded all the drivers from and they all work well. If worst comes to worst, you can use the default wi-fi driver that Windows 7 suggests. The S10-3t has a simple Broadcom card (4313 if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: I was trying to get the windows driver. That's where I first encountered the problem. It knew it was a network device, but it didn't know what and it couldn't find any driver for it. So, I went to Google. I have solved it now. I'm not sure what driver site I got it from, but the name of the driver is "superuser.com". Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, the name of the driver is "IN2WLN28WW5.exe". I couldn't remember the name of this site so I copy pasted it. I should not go on here half asleep :)